# Carga com tarefa Ant e EAP 7x "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException"

Tags: java, script, deploy, webserver, ant

Eu faço uma compilação de script usando a tarefa de formigas, a carga e a plataforma de aplicativos **JBOSS EAP** 7, abaixo segue meu código-fonte:

```
<taskdef resource="cargo.tasks">            
  <classpath>
    <fileset dir="${common.lib.dir}/cargo">
      <include name="**/*.jar"/>                                   
    </fileset>
  </classpath>
</taskdef> 

<macrodef name="start-jboss">
        <attribute name="jboss-home" default="${jboss.home}" />
        <attribute name="jboss-configuration" default="standalone" />
        <attribute name="jboss-hostname" default="${jboss.hostname}" />
        <attribute name="jboss-port" default="8081" />
        <attribute name="ear-file" default="${ear.jms.dist.dir}\NomeEAR.ear" />


<sequential>            
  <cargo
    containerId="wildfly10x"
    id="${jboss.refid}"
    home="@{jboss-home}"
    output="@{jboss-home}/@{jboss-configuration}/log/server.log"
    log="@{jboss-home}/@{jboss-configuration}/log/cargo.log"
    timeout="${jboss.start.timeout}"
    action="start">
    <configuration>
       <property name="cargo.hostname" value="@{jboss-hostname}" />
       <property name="cargo.servlet.port" value="@{jboss-port}" />
       <property name="cargo.remote.username" value="admin"/>
       <property name="cargo.remote.password" value="admin123"/>                        
       <property name="cargo.jboss.configuration" value="@{jboss-configuration}" />
       <property name="cargo.jboss.modules.dir" value="modules" />                      
       <property name="cargo.jvmargs" value="${jboss.jvmargs}" />
       <deployable type="ear" file="@{ear-file}" />
   </configuration>
  </cargo>
 </sequential>  
</macrodef>
```

Quando eu executar a tarefa **Ant** pelo terminal para o servidor inicial, mas recebo o seguinte erro:

-- *********************************************************************

```
2018-01-28 15:52:25,524 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWS022117: Invalid address provided: MYSERVER
    at org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig.toIPv6URLFormat(AbstractServerConfig.java:158)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig.setWebServiceHost(AbstractServerConfig.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.config.ServerConfigImpl.setWebServiceHost(ServerConfigImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.dmr.WSSubsystemAdd.createServerConfig(WSSubsystemAdd.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.dmr.WSSubsystemAdd.performBoottime(WSSubsystemAdd.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.performBoottime(AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.performRuntime(AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)



Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class br.com.NomeEAR.vida.dominio.service.faturamento.impl.BoletoFaturaColetivaService with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.NomeEARVida-ear-jms.ear.NomeEARVida-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
        ... 10 more
```

-- ********************************************************************

Essas dependências são jdk e a orelha está funcionando no eclipse IDE oxygen.

Obrigado por me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo a minha pergunta, siga abaixo esta solução

Em standalone.xml, coloco essa fonte de código

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <global-modules>
                <module name="mycompany.jdk8" slot="main"/>
            </global-modules>
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
```

Obrigado por me ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Eu descubro o problema, o Enterprise Jboss Application Platform tem um bug para conectar ao servidor com nome contém " _ ". Depois disso mudei o nome do servidor sem o " _ " e resolvi o meu problema.

Grato
Zenas Reis

or

Hello guys

I discover the problem, the Enterprise Jboss Application Platform has a bug to connect to the server with name contains " _ ". After that I changed the server name without the " _ " and solved my problem.

thankful
Zenas Reis